# Show the quantified statements are not logically equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

∀x(P(x) ⊕ Q(x)) and (∀xP(x)) ⊕ (∀xQ(x))

What I did was simplify the first statement

Ǝx ~(P(x) ↔ Q(x))                       Expression for inclusive or

Ǝx ~((P(x) -> Q(x)) ^ (Q(x) -> P(x)))   Expression for biconditional

Ǝx ~(~(P(x) V Q(x)) ^ ~(Q(x) V P(x)))   Expression for implication

Ǝx ((P(x) V Q(x)) V (Q(x) V P(x)))      DeMorgan’s law and double negation

Ǝx (P(x) V Q(x))                        Indempotent law

Then I said suppose this statement is true in a certain universe. We can say that P(a) is true or Q(a) is true. If Q(a) is true, then Ǝx P(x) is true, and by the rule of amplification we can say that Ǝx (P(x) V Q(x)) is true. Same thing applies for P(a).

For the second I simplified

~(∀xP(x)) ↔ (∀xQ(x))                                Expression for inclusive or

~(((∀xP(x)) -> (∀xQ(x))) ^ ((∀xQ(x)) -> (∀xP(x))))  Expression for bicondtional

~(~((∀xP(x)) V (∀xQ(x))) ^ ~((∀xQ(x)) V (∀xP(x))))  Expression for implication

(((∀xP(x)) V (∀xQ(x))) V ((∀xQ(x)) V (∀xP(x)))) DeMorgan’s + double negation

∀xP(x) V ∀xQ(x)                                     Indempotent law

But I'm not really sure how to explain this in words. I'm also not completely sure if I'm doing this whole question the correct way.

Comment: $(Q(x)\to P(x))$ is $(\neg Q(x)\vee P(x))$ *not* $\neg (Q(x)\vee P(x))$

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I still need to sharpen my simplfying skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disprove logical equivalence through a counterexample. Think about Natural numbers as a domain, $q(x)=1$ if x even and $p(x)=1$ if x is odd .

What happens to the left side? What happens to the right side ?

Comment: Originally I had something similar but I was thinking that maybe I'd have to show they are not logically equivalent in any universe. Or would it be ok just to use one universe as an example?

Comment: Yes that would be enough. You are disproving a statement, so you only need a counterexample. If they were logical equivalent they would have to be equivalent for every universe. So you just find one universe and interpretation where they aren't

Comment: Ah ok thank you. My original example was this:Let P(x) = “x^2>0” and Q(x) = “x^2=0” where x is the universe of all real numbers.

For the first statement ∀x(P(x) ⊕ Q(x)), every value but zero is true for x^2>0, so when x=any number but 0, P(x) is true, and Q(x) is false. When x=0, P(x) is false and Q(x) is true. This renders the statement true.
For the second statement, (∀xP(x)) ⊕ (∀xQ(x)), since P(x) and Q(x) each have their own quantifier attached, the value 0 makes P(x) false and any value but 0 makes Q(x) false, which would render the entire statement false.
Does this make sense?

Comment: And when two statements arent logically equivalent. They dont have to be logically inequivalent for every universe. There can be universes where they are equivalent.

Comment: Yes your example works aswell, i believe.

Comment: You can also prove the implication from right to left isn't a tautology with another counterexample, for example with $P(x) = \top$ and $Q(x) = (x^2 > 0)$.